# Time dependent actions for approval process?

Tags: approval-process, time-dependent-workflow

I can't seem to find anything on this, but do I have any time-based abilities with approval processes?

For instance, the object is submitted for approval and assigned to an approver.  No approval/rejection has occurred in 24 hours so I need to update a custom field.

Is anything like this possible?  If not, would I be able to accomplish something similar with workflow rules?

Your knowledge on this subject would help me tremendously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Workflow Rule, Process Builder, or Record-Triggered Flow could all be used for your purpose. You simply need to include a Field Update to kick off the delay mechanism.